# How to use terms aggregation results as a new filter in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm facing this problem with a query:

We have an index containing all the sessions started, containing the start date timestamp, the MAC address etc.

I want to retrieve all the unique macs that has a session started in the last 10 minutes and then check if these MACs are new (only one appearence in all times) or already has been seen (maybe 2 months ago), and how many times have been seen.

For example, doing the initial query for macs seen in the last 10 minutes, we get MAC A and MAC B. The MAC A has previous documents (2 months ago, and 12 days ago) and MAC B has no previous documents. The results should be: MAC A -> 3, MAC B -> 1

I am doing this approach, but all I can get is a list of MACs for the last 10 minutes and another for all the time:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "product_type": {
              "value": "FREE"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "transactions": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "display_range": {
            "range": {
              "start_timestamp": {
                "from": "2017-05-17T09:00:00Z",
                "to": "2017-05-17T09:10:00Z"
              }
            }
          },
          "all_days_range": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "unique_macs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "calling_station_id",
            "size": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!